# Resolve different decorated instances depending on consumer with structuremap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

The application is an ASP.NET MVC webapp built up by repositories fronted by a concrete service layer for backend. I use structure map 3 as IoC to inject the repositories for each concrete service. For logging/caching etc. I use decorated repositories which also is setup with structure map.

The application has a public and non-public part. The non-public part is where some super users log in and create and update content. The public part consists of http handlers and is exposed on the web and handles 99.99% of all requests to the application.

I would like to configure structure map to use cache decorated repositories when instances are resolved in the http handlers but not in the rest of the application. I would also like to inject a different logger to the service when resolved in http handlers.

Is this possible to get different setups of the same interface implementation depending on the consumer?

```
public interface IEntityRepository<IEntity>
{
}

public class ContentService : IEntityService
{
   public ContentService(IEntityRepository<Content> repoistory, ILogger logger)
   {

   } 
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is actually quite hard to achieve, even with other DI libraries. An easy workaround would be to create a second container instance that will resolve your http handlers, and add the extra decorator to the configuration of that container.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE that this solution doesn't provide the feature you are looking for - the delegate that is passed into the `DecorateAllWith` is only called once for each type that is resolved.**

---

The `DecorateAllWith` method has an overload that can be used to analyse the type being created and filter accordingly

```
[Fact]
public void DecorateAllWith_Filtered_IsNotReturned()
{
    var container = new StructureMap.Container(registry =>
    {
        registry.Scan(x =>
        {
            x.TheCallingAssembly();
            x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IEntityRepository<>));

        });
        registry.For(typeof(IEntityRepository<>))
            .DecorateAllWith(typeof(CachingDecorator<>), instance => false);
    });

    var result = container.GetInstance<IEntityRepository<Entity1>>();

    Assert.IsNotType<CachingDecorator<Entity1>>(result);
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP needs 'context based injection' where whether or not the decorator should be applied should depend on the type it is injected into. In his case, a `IEntityRepository<T>` should be decorated when it is injected into an HTTP handler, and it should not be decorated otherwise. I don't think this contextual information is information in the `instance`.

Comment: Hello again! =) That seems like what I am looking for but I am not sure what the instance object is and cant find any info about it. How would I see if the IEntityRepository was beeing resolved from within my http handler?

Comment: @Steven I agree that your point is quite valid - the delegate is not restricted to analysing the object instance - it could also check for things such as `HttpContext.Current` - this is not a full answer but the extension point offers the *possibility*.

Comment: @Niclas `instance` is the object that is to be decorated, it doesn't even need to be called `instance`. The documentation for `DecorateAllWith` is shocking in how little there is. @Steven's point is also valid - you may not be able find out exactly what object the `instance` is being injected into.

Comment: @qujck: But do note that the `Func<Instance, bool>` delegate will be called *once* per closed-generic type. So you can't use it to check whether or not you're in a http handler through its context, because that will determine whether or not to decorate it everywhere.

Comment: @qujck: I'm seeing some weird behavior with `DecorateAllWith`. Seems that the `Func<Instance, bool>` predicate is called for every instance in your registration, not only for implementations of `For(typeof(IEntityRepository<>))`. Weird!

Comment: @Steven: Ahh.. thats why it didnt work. I tried to set a flag HttpContext.Current.Items["isPublicRequest"] = true; which I then tried to use in the filter function. But it only worked once depending on if the first request was to the httphandler or not. But now I know why anyways. So is there a solution - or am I completely stuck?

Comment: @niclas: well, this us outside my field of expertise. I don't know how to fix this with StructureMap.

Comment: @Steven: I managed to get a working solution manually decorating the instance when using a non-generic or closed generic. Is it possible to do with another IoC?

Comment: @Niclas: You could try Simple Injector (qujck and I are both developers for Simple Injector). If you ask a new question about this and tag it with 'simple-injector' I'll do my best to answer it for you. But do note that -as I said before- as far as I know, no DI library currently allows this scenario out-of-the-box (not even Simple Injector).